# How do you see errors from the Controller in xunit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, xunit

I used this to setup my xunit integration tests.

*Edit: I posted the wrong link.  Here's the correct one.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I'm making some call that throws an error

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"),
    "/api/Lookup/ProvinceState/GetAllProvinceStates");
var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);

Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
```

The status code is `500` and the response data is an html page with the error.  I  was hoping that I could get the output right in my test window.

I added `.Configure(x => { });` to my `CustomWebApplicaitonFactory` which prevented the startup from calling `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`.  Then it started putting out text.  So I just wrote that text to the console in the test, but I don't want to have to keep doing that for every test.

There must be a canonical solution.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your call shown here calls to an API endpoint, which means your asp.net core api would have to be run as a separate process, then attach a debugger to that. There are many other ways to debug as well, including a test host https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @Tim debugging hasn't been a problem for me.  I can set break points and inspect things.  But I don't want to have to keep doing that, when an error message in the console could point me to the issue in 2 seconds.

Comment: Well, if you want it to return errors from the service, you need to pass these back as a response somehow.

Comment: One thing I tried to do, and I thought I was onto something, in that `.Configure` override, I tried to build out a custom exception handler, but I couldn't get access to a `TestOutputHelper` because that happens before DI, and creating a new one didn't help either.  There has to be some way to dump that error to the console.  I can override the error handing routine.  How am I the only one that's ever tried to do this?

Comment: Still not entirely sure I understand the problem scenario, but have you tried just putting your Controller methods into `try/catch` blocks?

Comment: I don't want to have to do that for every controller either.

Comment: Again, what you are running here is essentially a `client` test, calling the API, so your output window is showing the client code and errors, not your API server.

Comment: Right.  But I have the facilities to override the error handler.  I should be able catch errors thrown by the `client` from the test project.

Comment: The errors are not thrown by the client.

Comment: Sorry.  The controller.  The test project can override the error handler of the MVC project.

Comment: I'm going to work on a minimal example.

Comment: That's a new concept to me. I've never seen one process handle the errors from another process like that, but maybe it's something in XUnit I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Overriding the startup is in that document from Microsoft.

Comment: That doesn't explain how you're hitting it from a different process.

Comment: It does.  The whole MVC is being replaced.  It explains it all in that document.  `IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>`  It's actually running in the same process.

Comment: You can create a custom middleware that returns the exception for you, in whatever format you want. You can then register this, when running into some specific environment which you can set in `CustomWebApplicationFactory`. To log to the console, you'll have to do it manually, I'm afraid.

Comment: To log the error to xunit output, you have to use `ITestOutputHelper`. To avoid repetition you could create a base test class to take care of the boilerplate for you.

Comment: @Tim I edited the question.  Apparently I posted the wrong link, which might account for some of the confusion.  I did figure it out, though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  Figured it out.  Basically, you don't want any exception handler at all.  You just want to let it keep falling out until it hits the xunit libraries.

*It actually turns out that this is more important than I once thought. If you don't do this properly, you won't get proper errors from Continuous Integration.*

When you first setup the MVC application you were provided with this little piece of code

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)        {
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); //This is the problem
    }
```

but you still want that line to execute during regular development.  It helps to have a pretty html error with all the JavaScript and CSS goodness.

So you have to override that during XUNIT.  Start with the link from Microsoft that I posted in the question.

It boilerplates with

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    //...
```

but the builder also has `.Configure(app => {});`

But you still need the MVC to start `app.UseMvc` inside the `Config` overrider.  You'll also need the `AddMvc` to the `ConfigureServices` overrider.  In fact, you can go back to your development/production `Startup.cs` and copy all the lines from inside the Configure function. At the very least, you should have:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> 
    : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup: class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services => { services.AddMvc(); }).Configure(app => { app.UseMvc(); });
    }
}
```

That will prevent your Startup methods from running.
I'll bet most people just gave up on this issue.  I really wish Microsoft would publish this.

*Edit: Look how awesome this works!*

Here it is in action.  Look at those hyperlinks.  I can now just click the link and it jumps right to that place in the code.  I actually fixed this error and came back to unfix it to show everyone.

[image: Error example]

Comment: One suggestion would be to define environments specifically for unit/integration testing and then spin this up explicitly in the WebApplicationFactory as part of the test initialization

Comment: Someone posted an answer on the link I provided.  I haven't tried it yet, but he says that's how he did it and wrote a blog about it. As soon as I get around to it, I will post the answer.